# The type cast failes when adding object to the collection

Tags: c#

I am a little bit lost with this exercise, the error that is throwing:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Ex02_School.Student' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Ex02_School.Student]'.

Thanks!

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ex02_School
{
    /**
     * Given students' names along with the grade that they are in, create a roster for the school.
     * In the end, you should be able to:
     * Add a student's name to the roster for a grade
     * Get a list of all students enrolled in a grade
     * Get a sorted list of all students in all grades. 
     * Grades should sort as 1, 2, 3, etc., and students within a grade should be sorted alphabetically by name.
     * Note that all students only have one name. 
     */

    
    public class School
    {
        public IEnumerable<Student> students;
        public void AddStudent(string student, int grade)
        {
            Student st = new Student(student, grade);
            students.Concat((IEnumerable<Student>)st);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetAllStudents()
        {
            return (IEnumerable<string>)students;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetStudentsForGrade(int grade)
        {

            var listGrade = students.Where(student => student.Grade == grade);
            return (IEnumerable<string>) listGrade;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Grade;

        public Student(string name, int grade)
        {
            Name= name;
            Grade = grade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do remember that [ask] states that readers should write descriptive question titles. Yours is currently anything but. Please edit your question.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Too obvious

```cs
// here you get type 'Student'
Student st = new Student(student, grade);
// And here you are trying to cast 'Student' into `IEnumerable<Student>`
students.Concat((IEnumerable<Student>)st);
```

The question is, why are you not getting design time compilation error which would prevent you to run this code?

Not sure what is the full intent there. But looks like Add Student should be done like this

```cs
public List<Student> students; // <-- this must be a list

public void AddStudent(string student, int grade)
{
    Student st = new Student(student, grade);
    students.Add(st); // <-- add to list
}
```

Lets look deeper. If you use `IEnumerable.Concat`, you take 2 collections, append one to another and produce another `IEnumerable`, while your original collections stays unchanged. Hence you need to `Add/Insert` item. But `IEnumerable` exists only fore selection or iteration. So, you need to use a type that has `Add`. `List` or `Dictionary`, there are other collections as well, which implement `IEnumerable`. But you cant just add to the collection via `IEnumerable`

```cs
var list = new List<Model>();
var en = (IEnumrable<Model>)list; // -- OK
en.Add(new Model()) // -- not OK, Add is not part of Ienumerable 
list.Add(new Model()) // -- OK
```

Comment: +1, but the reason the OP is not getting a compile time error vs. a runtime error is because the compiler cannot determine that `Student` does not in fact implement the interface `IEnumerable<Student>` since a subclass of `Student` could in principle implement that interface.  Also, might be worth pointing out that `Concat` is a pure function; so even if everything else worked it would be a no-op since `Concat` doesn't mutate state.

Comment: If `Student` were `sealed`, a compiler error would be emitted.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks. I agree. I thought the `Concat` was used by mistake. Right, implement `IEnumerable<T>` + `Concat` = one collection + another. And, yes, it would generate new subset and not add to the existing collection. Hence, I changed that to `Add` and `List<T>`

Comment: For sure!  I was just trying to suggest some ideas that would improve the answer.  Absolutely nothing wrong with the guidance you've already given.

Comment: i.e. if `Concat` was used by mistake, then the OP was confused, so maybe elaborate on it was all I meant. :)